# Как исправить прыжок?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Реализацию прыжка в 2D платформере сделал через "rigidbody.AddForce", при получении урона, происходит тоже самое (то есть отталкивание). Из-за этого происходит баг, если перед получением урона использовать прыжок, происходит слишком сильное отталкивание (я так понял эффекты суммируются). Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Не работал с Unity3D, но могу предложить завести флаг, булевое значение которого отражает прыгает ли сейчас Ваш персонаж. Если персонаж ещё не приземлился - не запускать дальнейшую отработку

Comment: А почему бы и нет, просто возможно в вашем случае стоит, как сказано ранее завести флаг, и по нему отталкивание в случае прыжка производить с понижающим коэффициентом, что согласуется с реальной физикой?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Дело в том, что такой флаг есть, а метод получения урона подталкивает независимо от булевого значения.

Comment: @Monomax как можно до прыжка считать будущее отталкивание?

Comment: @Артём будущее отталкивание считается по физической формуле путем сложения векторов и действующих сил по закону Ньютона (если не ошибаюсь по второму закону)

Comment: @Monomax спасибо, поищу точную формулу

Answer (score 0):

Как выше сказали, сделать булевое значение isGrounded. Не буду долго писать вот: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAPVBTKk3Ww
Где то после 1:30:00 наверное, там объясняют

Comment: Я смотрел это видео, isGrounded есть в коде, но все ровно не всегда срабатывает